# laravel form generates wrong action url / route error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create a form in laravel to update some data.
I started off by using the following in my blade template to fill the form with data from a model:

```
{{ Form::model($sensor, array('action' => 'settingsController@editSensor', $sensor->s_id)) }}
```

$sensor is send to the view from the controller in this way:

```
return view('settings.sensors.edit')->with('sensor', App\Sensor::find($sensorId))
```

The documentation isn't to clear about whether or not I also need to use  Form::open , but the form open tag was already created, so I figured this would be enough.

In my routes I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/settings/sensors/edit/{sensorId}',['as' => 'sensor.edit', 'uses' => 'settingsController@editSensor']);
Route::post('/settings/sensors/edit/{sensorId}',['as' => 'sensor.edit', 'uses' => 'settingsController@editSensor']);
```

I could access the form by going to a url like http://localhost:8000/settings/sensors/edit/105 , the prefilling with data from the model worked like a charm.

The problem I had was that the submit button did now work. It would submit to http://localhost:8000/settings/sensors/edit/%7BsensorId%7D 
Clearly, the sensorId parameter was not being substituded properly.

I rewrote the Form::model function call after some googling to this:

```
{{ Form::model($sensor, array('route' => route('sensor.edit',$sensor->s_id)), $sensor->s_id) }}
```

When I now open the page, I directly get this error: Route [http://localhost:8000/settings/sensors/edit/105] not defined

That seems odd, since I made no change to the routes, and there is a route defined for this url. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially duplicating the route call. When you do `Form::model($sensor, array('route' =>`, Laravel already knows that you're trying to access a named route, and is expecting a route name. So when you then do `route(...)`, it first converts that route call before trying to look for a route named that.

In other words, it's not complaining that the page `http://localhost:8000/settings/sensors/edit/105` does not exist - it's complaining that no route has that as its `as` name.

Remove it, and replace it by an array with the route name and the parameter instead. Then you can also get rid of the extra `$sensor->s_id`, like this:

```
{{ Form::model($sensor, array('route' => array('sensor.edit', $sensor->s_id))) }}
```